# Error with real UR5e connected via 5G

Tags: ros, microcontroller, ros-melodic, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have script that controls UR5e using haptic device, it works perfectly connected directly using ethernet, but it doesn't work when i use 2 5G routers (arround 70ms ping). When i launch ur5e_bringup it gives me that error:

```
[ERROR] [1621327595.576990704]: Could not get fresh data package from robot
[ERROR] [1621327596.989480803]: Can't accept new commands. Controller is not running.
```

Im using scaled_pos_traj_controller and it stopped shortly after launching the bringup.

ROS Melodic and Ubuntu 18 using UR ROS Drivers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378503/error-with-real-ur5e-connected-via-5g/) by [Trelis98](https://answers.ros.org/users/74753/trelis98/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have script that controls UR5e using haptic device, it works perfectly connected directly using ethernet, but it doesn't work when i use 2 5G routers (arround 70ms ping).

The driver uses multiple connections to the robot controller, some of which are relatively high bandwidth (both RTDE and the "real-time" data broadcasts on `tcp://:30003`). Missed packets (due to noise on your link fi, or because of (temporarily) dropped connections) will interfere with the driver's correct functioning.

Additionally, the `ros_control` approach used by the current implementation is not very well suited for lossy connections. For e-Series controllers, a stable connection capable of supporting the 500 Hz control rate is essentially required. The 70 ms latency you quote is already multiple control periods of additional latency (on-top of the latency already present in the UR controller itself), which will further degrade control performance.

Overall, I would not recommend attempting to control an (industrial) robot controller in real-time over anything but a wired ethernet connection.

(note: this is not really specific to `ur_robot_driver`: I'm not aware of *any* real-time capable control interface for industrial robots which is suitable for use with a wireless connection)

---

Edit: seeing as 5G is mentioned: it *may* be possible to configure a dedicated connection with sufficient QoS parameters (at the "5G level", so not at the ROS topic level), but that would be out-of-scope of the driver. You'd have to look into getting that setup for your system.

I'd still personally be hesitant to use such a setup, but it may offer a way out.

---

Edit 2: your question reminded me of an open PR over at `ros2/design` which discusses mapping ROS 2 topic-level QoS to "unique network flows" for networks such as 5G infrastructures. See [ros2/design#304](https://github.com/ros2/design/pull/304).

While you're not using ROS 2, the authors of that design document may be interested in your use-case, and they may even be able to suggest approaches which could make whatever it is you're doing work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1